# distributing a command line application

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

Python newbie here. I'm trying to package a console app following this [doc](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html). To this end I created the following [directory structure](https://github.com/armandino/TxtStyle):

```
.
├── bin
│   └── txts
├── setup.py
└── txtstyle
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── ...
    └── [snip]
```

My app has one executable script which I placed under `bin`. I could successfully run

```
python setup.py sdist
```

and create a tar.gz. However I can't execute the script under bin due to import errors.

So my question is how can the script access the main module from under bin?

Comment: You didn't forget to do `python ./setup.py install`, did you? Your script works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the package.  This puts all modules in the global module path, and thus allows you to import them.  For development, use `python setup.py develop` which links the modules into the module python instead of copying them.  This way you don't need to reinstall the package each time you changed a module.

There is a tool called [`virtualenv`](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=virtualenv&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv&ei=DHLDTvbUMInEswaz5vDWCw&usg=AFQjCNEaDRdSjU7Kpgeax6W6-98APWCRVg) which creates virtual python environments.  You can install modules into such environments without touching the global Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `develop` parameter.